# Scanning elements of an array in c

Tags: c, arrays

If I declare an array of n elements, while scanning the elements using a single for loop, I noticed the number of elements entered can be greater than n (if I keep pressing SPACE after each element), but when I print the array it gives  only first n elements. I am using code blocks.

Why?

[image]

Comment: because `for(i=0;i<n;++i){ scanf("%d", &elements[i]); }`

Comment: but while scanning,after the nth entry it should not scan further, right?

Comment: Loop is executed n times. More is not.

Comment: please see the image added.5 is the number of elements i want in my array.third line indicates printing the elements.in second line even though i wanted to scan only 5 elements ,i can make more entries if i keep pressing SPACE after 5 th element.my doubt is shouln't it stop after 5th element only.why do i have to press ENTER to stop the scanning of input?

Comment: Input that has not been used at the input is still in the input buffer. It does not simply be used.

Comment: Site rules require a question to be self-contained. Do not post images or external links in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can enter multiple inputs by pressing space but to complete taking input scanf demands 'enter' to be pressed. so when you press enter scanf terminates.

when you use a for loop for scanning, your first scanf executes, and it is supposed to take first input but you provide multiple inputs (may or may not be more than n) using space. and then when you press enter scanf stops taking input, assign the value and terminates. Then you second scanf gets executed (in loop), now you already have unused inputs in your queue. so input for this scanf is fetched from input buffer instead and you are not bothered for another inputs, it happens until your for loop doesn't terminate or your input buffer doesn't get empty, in that case you will be asked for more inputs.